# Unrecognized selector setting alpha for a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, iboutlet

I'm getting an unrecognized selector exception trying to set the alpha on a `UIImageView`, but I don't understand why this should be seeing a `UIImageView` inherits from `UIView` and `alpha` is a property of that.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView              *pulldownTab;

...
self.pulldownTab.alpha = 1.0;


2013-05-21 07:33:32.964 TestControl[655:907] -[__NSCFNumber setAlpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e587fa0
```

** UPDATE **
Moral of the story - Solved. be careful with key value coding, a call to this function was being made earlier

```
- (void) fadeToAlphaValue: (double) alpha forKeyPath: (NSString*) keyPath
{
    NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:alpha];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kFadeAnimationDuration
                     animations:^ {
                        [self setValue:number forKeyPath:keyPath];
                     }];
}


   [self fadeToAlphaValue:0.0 forKeyPath:@"self.pulldownTab"];
```

Comment: Where do you set the pulldownTab? It seems to be a NSNumber

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are assigning the `IBOutlet` properly in the `interface Builder`?

The reference is not properly working, when you access to `self.pulldownTab` is accessing to a `NSCFNumber` variable in memory.

Comment: Hi, yes its being assigned correctly in IB  and  is successfully being displayed in the GUI. At the time of the exception the variable watch window says: _pulldownTab = (UIImageView*) 0x1fda1a00 (double) 1.

Comment: Are you using the variable somewhere else? There's something wrong with it at the moment of setting the alpha

Comment: Elsewhere its transform is set, [UIView animateWithDuration:kPulldownAnimationDuration animations:^{self.pulldownTab.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);}];.

Comment: There is a slight difference betweem `_pulldonwTab` and self.pulldownTab. You should check for both variables in your code, you might synthesised your property and used wiht `_` somewhere else. It's definitely not showing up properly in the watch. You could also try the `po` command in Xcode command line, po [self.pullDown class]; and po [_pullDown class]; and see what's printing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. In my case, I was setting *myTextView*, but not the *.text* property, earlier in the code, like this:

```
self.myTextView = @"text";
```

instead of what I should have been doing:

```
self.myTextView.text = @"text";
```

for some reason this didn't throw any errors at this point, but it created an issue later when I tried to set the alpha property on an NSString (which doesn't have such a thing) :)

Anyways, just look for any stupid mistakes like this in your code before the *.alpha* property is being set - they'll likely be the cause of the problem!